# What is an adjective that distinguishes between a random walk and a fuzzed deterministic process?

Tags: terminology, random-walk, time-series

I am writing a computer program where the user has the choice of one of two sequences, $a_k$ or $b_k$.  These sequences are defined as follows:

- $a_k = c k + \varepsilon_k$;
- $b_k = b_{k-1} + c + \varepsilon_k$

in both cases, $\varepsilon_k$ are i.i.d. zero-mean random variables and c is a fixed constant.  That is, $a_k$ is an arithmetic series with noise superimposed, whereas $b_k$ is an AR(1) autoregressive process.

Is there a good adjective that distinguishes between the two cases, i.e. something to take the place of ????? in

make_series(growth_rate = $c$, noise_dist = $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, ????? = true)

Comment: The $a_k$ would be homoscedastic.

Comment: @Joe: I thought about that, but I thought it was confusing because in the context of time series you often say that a series $x_k$ is homoskedastic if the differences $\Delta x_k$ are.

Comment: Interesting. Can you use ```autoregressive=true``` to select $b_k$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not an ajective. They are instances of completely different classes of models:

$a_k$ is a linear trend with zero intercept.

$b_k = b_{k-1} + c + \epsilon_k = b_{k-2} + 2c + \epsilon_k + \epsilon_{k-1} = \\
=b_{k-3} + 3c + \sum_{j=0}^2\epsilon_{k-j} = b_{k-T} + Tc + \sum_{j=0}^{T-1}\epsilon_{k-j} \hspace{.2cm} \forall T \in \mathbb{N}$

I.e. $b_k$ is a random walk with drift c.